# To prevent access other pages of asp.net application on button click

Tags: asp.net

I have one requiremt like There is button which is named Start/Stop. When he clicks the button first time number of hours caluclated until he clicked second time on same button (i.e Stops).

E.g:- He clicks first time (time interval should be caluclated) and he clicks second time (stop) after 8 hours. So total time is 8 hours.

2) When he clicks first time (i.e Start ), appliation should not allowed to access of other pages. Once he clicks second time (i.e Stop) then it should allow the application.

Thanks,
Ravikiran

Comment: Can you elaborate? What do you mean other pages? How can you prevent user from typing page address directly into browser address bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the way of making it work is to use the modal popup covering the entire page once the user clicked the start button and put the second button on the top of it to close . jqueryUI modal popup is one of the example. My solution does not stop user to type the path in the URL and try. In that case you can put the value in Session with the flag saying

```
if(Session["Started"] != null)
{
    //redirect to same page where the timer is running
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be almost impossible to stop the user from going to another page via the address bar.

Ignoring the address bar problem for a minute, you will need to have client-side logic to check for events happening in the browser (i.e. user closing a tab, hitting back button, etc.), which if you are only using server-side logic it will be too late to catch.

It really sounds like you need for this to be a WinForms/WPF/Silverlight application instead of a browser-based application, because of your need to restrict navigation.